# grep command to find out how many times any character is followed by '.'

Tags: regex, bash, sorting, unix, grep

I have to find out how often any character is followed by a period (.) with the help of grep. After finding how many times character is followed by period and then I have to sort the result in ascending order.

For example in this string: "Find my input. Output should be obtained. You need to find output."

The output should be something like this:

```
d 1 
t 2
```

What I have done so far :

```
cat filename | grep -o "*." | sort -u
```

But it is not working as intended.

Any ideas how to solve this? I have to perform this operation on huge library of books in .txt files.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, fixed it.

Comment: @N3o: Do you want to sort it on counts or characters ?

Comment: @batMan I want to sort it on counts , cyrus solution seems to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An iterative approach with GNU grep:

```
grep -o '.\.' filename | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
          1 d.
          2 t.
```

---

```
grep -Po '.(?=\.)' filename | sort | uniq -c
```

Output:

```
          1 d
          2 t
```

---

```
grep -Po '.(?=\.)' filename | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

Output:

```
d 1
t 2
```

Comment: Btw: it is possible to replace `sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'` by `awk '{a[$1]+=1} END{for(i in a) print i,a[i]}'`.

Comment: This will require another `sort -n` at the end as op wants final output to be sorted

Comment: @batMan: Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

With single GNU **awk** process:

```
awk -v FPAT='.[.]' 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc" }
       { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[substr($i,1,1)]++ }
       END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i] }' filename
```

The output:

```
d 1
t 2
```

Comment: Although it's a single process but I guess this will be slower than the grep solution as this will involve more internal transactions/function calls. I may be wrong but it will be interesting to find out which one is processing faster. @N3o : Can you let us know which is faster by executing both these solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

This one is ok too

```
echo "Find my input. Output should be obtained. You need to find output."| grep -o ".\." | sort | uniq -c | rev | tr -d .
```